# Crystal Report: How to display All section when no data?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

How to display **All section** on the **Crystal Report** when no data?

I am used to **jasper report** where one property for `When No Data` we set 
`All Sections, No details`,

so we can see our design on pdf file.

How i can get the same with Crystal reports?

Thanks in advance !

Anand

Comment: Couldn't understand your requirement? What are you trying to show if there is no data.... empty design is a bblank page what is your requirement

Comment: are you using stored procedure?? can you elaborate what you are trying to say?

Comment: No, it's a simple select query,actually on my Crystal report i have Page Header text and in body section i have one image.select query fetching the record according to date, if there is no record coming according to my query(date) then i want to show page header text and image on the report with blank data.